# How to select randomly and fairly data in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, dataset

How can I select randomly and fairly some data from a dataset in matlab?

When we use the randperm function to select data, they are random and fair?

Comment: Yes I think you are ok. Example: `m = 6; Data = magic(m)
shuffle = randperm(m); Data = Data(shuffle, :);` In this way you shuffle your rows.

Answer (score 1):

As you already suggested, selecting `k` uniformly random chosen rows out of `n` can be done with `randperm`, assuming you don't want duplication.

Example:

```
dataSet = rand(1000,4);
idx = randperm(size(dataSet,1),10)
dataSet(idx,:)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
sample = randsample(data,k);
```

takes `k` values sampled uniformly at random, without replacement, from the values in the vector `data`. See above link for other options.

Equivalent code with `randperm`:

```
ind = randperm(numel(data));
sample = data(ind(1:k));
```

Yes, either of these approaches gives *random* samples, and yes, they are *fair*. I assume that by "fair" you mean "uniform": each entry of `data` is picked with the same probability.

Answer (score 0):

anything that uses uniform distribution is "fair". because the output is supposed to be distributed randomly in an specific range. for example, **rand** function in matlab.